# C++: Error cuando recopilo programa "undefined reference to `Clase::Clase();'"

Tags: c++, vscode, undefined

Estoy haciendo un programa de un banco pero a la hora de crear objetos en el *main.cpp* me salta un error de indefinido.

Estos son los archivos:

**cajero.cpp**

```
#include "cajero.hpp"

Cajero::Cajero(){
    this->valorCaja = 0;
};
void Cajero::depositar(float cantidad){this->valorCaja += cantidad;};
float Cajero::saldoEnCaja(){return this->valorCaja;};
```

**cajero.hpp**

```
#ifndef cajero_hpp
#define cajero_hpp 

#include <stdio.h>

class Cajero{
     float valorCaja;
public:
        Cajero();
void    depositar(float);
float   saldoEnCaja();
};

#endif /* cajero_hpp */
```

**cliente.cpp**

```
#include "cliente.hpp"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

Cliente::Cliente(string nom, float depo){
    this->nombre = nom;
    this->aDepositar = depo;
    this->sigCliente = NULL;
};

float Cliente::paraDeposito(){return this->aDepositar;};

void  Cliente::setSigCliente(Cliente *dirCliente){this->sigCliente = dirCliente;};

Cliente * Cliente::getSigCliente(){return this->sigCliente;};

float Cliente::getADepostiar(){return this->aDepositar;};

string Cliente::getNombre(){return this->nombre;};
```

**cliente.hpp**

```
#ifndef cliente_hpp
#define cliente_hpp

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Cliente{

    string nombre;
     float aDepositar;
     Cliente * sigCliente;
public:
    Cliente(string, float);
    float paraDeposito();
    void setSigCliente(Cliente *);
    Cliente * getSigCliente();
    float getADepostiar();
    string getNombre();
};

#endif /* cliente_hpp */
```

**colaCliente.cpp**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "colaCliente.hpp"
#include "cliente.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


ColaCliente::ColaCliente(){
    this->inicioCola = NULL;
    this->finCola = NULL;
    this->numClientesFormados = 0;
};
    void ColaCliente::agregaCliente(string nom, float depo)
    {
        Cliente * nvoCliente = new Cliente(nom, depo);
        if (this->getIncioCola() == NULL)
        {
            this->setInicioCola(nvoCliente);
            this->setFinCola(nvoCliente);
            this->incrementaCliente();
        }
        else
        {
            this->getFinCola()->setSigCliente(nvoCliente);
            this->setFinCola(nvoCliente);
            this->incrementaCliente();
        }


    };

    void ColaCliente::atiendeCliente()
    {
            if(this->getIncioCola()==NULL){
                cout << "Cola Vacía"<<endl;
            }
            else{
                Cliente * aux = this->getIncioCola();
                this->setInicioCola(this->getIncioCola()->getSigCliente());
                this->decrementaCliente();                
            }
    };

    void ColaCliente::vizualizaCola()
    {
        Cliente * aux = this->getIncioCola();
        cout << "Clientes Formados: "<< this->getNumClientesFormados()
        <<endl;

        while (aux != NULL)
        {
            cout << "Nombre: " << aux->getNombre()<< "a Depositar: " << aux->getADepostiar()
            <<endl;
        }
        
    };

    void ColaCliente::setInicioCola(Cliente * cli){this->inicioCola = cli;};

    void ColaCliente::setFinCola(Cliente *fin){this->finCola = fin;};

    void ColaCliente::incrementaCliente(){this->numClientesFormados++;};

    void ColaCliente::decrementaCliente(){this->numClientesFormados--;};

    Cliente * ColaCliente::getIncioCola(){return this->inicioCola;};

    Cliente * ColaCliente::getFinCola(){return this->finCola;};

    int ColaCliente::getNumClientesFormados(){return this->numClientesFormados;};
```

**colaCliente.hpp**

```
#ifndef colaCliente_hpp
#define colaCliente_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include "cliente.hpp"

class ColaCliente
{
     Cliente * inicioCola;
     Cliente * finCola;
     int numClientesFormados;
public:
    ColaCliente();
    void agregaCliente(string, float);
    void atiendeCliente();
    void vizualizaCola();
    void setInicioCola(Cliente *);
    void setFinCola(Cliente *);
    void incrementaCliente();
    void decrementaCliente();
    Cliente * getIncioCola();
    Cliente * getFinCola();
    int getNumClientesFormados();  
};

#endif /* colaCliente_hpp */
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cajero.hpp"
#include "cliente.hpp"
#include "colaCliente.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    //Cajero * nvoCajero= new Cajero();
    ColaCliente * caja1= new ColaCliente();

    //caja1->agregaCliente("Felipe", 200.00);
   

    //caja1->vizualizaCola();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Cada que creo un objeto en el main me sale el error

> C:\Users\Publi\AppData\Local\Temp\ccynICwC.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `ColaCliente::ColaCliente()'
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Ya traté compilando con *g++ mian.cpp* , *cliente.cpp*, etc.
¡Parece ser que nada me funciona!

Comment: Cual es el comando en especifico que estas usando para compilar?

Comment: Comentario al margen: imagino que nada más fue un error de tipeo lo de _mian.cpp_, en lugar de _main.cpp_.

Answer (score 0):

> Ya traté compilando con g++ mian.cpp , cliente.cpp, etc. ¡Parece ser que nada me funciona!

Los archivos `*.cpp` se compilan en objetos intermedios, msvc los compila en `NombreDeArchivo.obj` y generalmente los compiladores populares en plataformas Linux compilan en `NombreDeArchivo.o`. Para generar el archivo intermedio debes pedir que se compilen **todos** los archivos `*.cpp`, parece que en tu comando falta `ColaCliente.cpp`.

Pero compilar no es suficiente, de nada vale tener el objeto intermedio si no lo enlazas al generar el ejecutable, después de compilarlo hay que llamar al enlazador. Te aconsejo que intentes compilar y enlazar por separado para ver si algún paso está fallando:

> ```
> g++ -c cajero.cpp
> g++ -c cliente.cpp
> g++ -c colaCliente.cpp
> g++ -c main.cpp
> g++ -o programa cajero.o cliente.o colaCliente.o main.o
> ```